# Assign number to alphabet in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

What I want to do is use an `array.each` to turn each letter into its corresponding letter in the alphabet plus nine. I know it's possible to put it against a `case` going through all 26 letters, but that seems unnecessary.

For example. Say the array is:

`["N", "O", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"]`

I want the array to become

`["23", "24", "29", "17", "19", "24", "17"]`

Comment: I believe your question is: I wish to convert each letter in an array of letters to its offset from 'A', plus 10. For example, "B" => 1 + 10 = 11. This is if the result is to be an array of integers, as has been assumed in the solutions. If you want these integers expressed as strings, as shown in your question, you should say so; else change that to an array of integers. "G" => 16, not 17. I suggest you edit your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way:

`arr.map {|ch| ch.ord - 'A'.ord + 10}`

Comment: I get the error

(eval):675: undefined method 'ord' for "N":String (NoMethodError)
 from (eval):675:in 'map'
 from (eval):675

Comment: @Bluethousandand2 That's because you are using Ruby 1.8, you should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution could be using

```
plus = 9
nothing = ["N", "O", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"]
alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
# => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", ..., "Z"] 
nothing.map { |d| alphabet.index(d) + 1 + plus }
# => [23, 24, 29, 17, 18, 23, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Ruby 1.8 version of rohit89's answer:

```
ary = ["N", "O", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"]
ary.map { |str| str[0] - ?A + 10 }
# => [23, 24, 29, 17, 18, 23, 16]
```

Note that if you can, you should update your Ruby installation since [version 1.8.7 is no longer supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/).

Answer (score 0):

A nice way is to use a hash.
First create the hash. I noticed you want the integer values to be formatted as strings, so the hash would be

```
hash = Hash[('A'..'Z').to_a.zip(("10".."37").to_a)]
```

If you want integer values, use the following hash instead

```
hash = Hash[('A'..'Z').to_a.zip((10..37).to_a)]
```

Then you can apply the hash on the array using map

```
print ["N", "O", "T", "H", "I", "N", "G"].map{|char| hash[char]}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$hash = {"A" => "1", "B" => "2", "C" => "3"}
$hash["A"] 
"1"

input = ["A", "C", "A"]
input.each do |me| #giggity
 print $hash[me]
 print " "
end

=> 1 3 1
```